# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server using prisma, supabase and redwood

Tags: prisma, supabase, redwoodjs

I want to do a migration using prisma, supabase and redwood.

The problem is that when I try to do `yarn redwood prisma migrate dev` I get this :
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNAb3.png)

My schema.prisma :

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider      = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = "native"
}

model profiles {
  id         String   @id @default(uuid())
  updatedat  DateTime?
  firstName  String?
  lastName   String?
  email      String @unique
}
```

I have in my .env the DATABASE_URL found on supabase -> project settings -> database.
The value looks like this : `postgresql://postgres:password@db.oteaeccdiheyyajfvmqb.supabase.co:5432/postgres`

It actually works when I try my application on my localhost with `yarn redwood dev` command. I can read and write my profile table.

Comment: You are able to connect to the database with this connection string through an IDE, right?

Comment: I can connect to it using psql.  
I just tried again today and it just worked.  
I don't know why I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem just now.
The "Error: P1001" disappeared after I used Telnet to connect to the db.

Try:

```
telnet db.oteaeccdiheyyajfvmqb.supabase.co 5432
```